# How do I set up Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting angular up and working. I tried the same code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2twk7v3z/) and it works, so I'm pretty lost here.

In my working directory I have my index.html, and a folder 'js' containing angular.min.js, angular.min.js.map, and my app.js. The angular files were downloaded today from angularjs.org (v1.2).

index.html:

```
<html>.                                                                            
  <head>                                                                           
   <title>The Title</title>                                                   
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">.
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>                       
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>               
  </head>                                                                          

  <body ng-app="page">                                                         
   <div ng-controller="bodyController">                                         

     <h2>{{title}}</h2>                                                           

     <p>{{description}}</p>                                                                                                                                                                           

   </div>                                                                         
  </body>                                                                          

</html>
```

app.js:

```
function() {                                                                        

  var app = angular.module('page',[]);                           

  app.controller('bodyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {.                    
      $scope.title = 'The food page';                                                
      $scope.description = 'Where you get your food and don\'t eat it, too';         
    }]);                                                                             

})();
```

I serve the working directory to my localhost using the npm http-server tool, and all I see in chrome are the 'unevaluated' expressions:

```
{{title}}
{{description}}
```

It must be something with my setup because the code is correct as proven by the jsfiddle. Anybody see something obviously wrong?

Comment: angular.js is not loading check its path.. check for errors in browser console

Answer (score 3):

Look in your browser's JavaScript console. It will be complaining that `angular` is undefined.

You need to load Angular **before** you try to use it.

Reverse the order of your `<script>` elements.